# How to set up execve call on nasm right?

Tags: linux, assembly, exec, nasm, system-calls

The following code shows

> relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.data'

```
 child:
    mov eax,11
    mov ebx,echo
    mov ecx,argv
    xor edx,edx
    int 0x80

section .data    
echo db '/bin/echo',0

argv0 db 'echo',0
argv1 db 'child excuted',0
argv db argv0, argv1
```

How I should set up execve call right?
I thought to put addresses in stack and use esp but I still need to know how to declare array of strings in nasm.

Comment: Pointers are not bytes. You should use `argv dd argv0, argv1, 0` to make them the proper size, and also NULL terminate the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jester suggested, you need to declare `argv` properly:

```
argv dd argv0, argv1, 0
```

`db` refers to defining a list of 8-bit bytes. `dw` would let you define 16-bit shorts. `dd` is for 32-bit numbers - on 32-bit Linux, this is the proper pointer size. (You would use `dq` on 64-bit, because that's a 64-bit number, which is the right pointer size in that case.)

`execve` expects a NULL-terminated list of pointers, so we use `dd` for each of our pointers, and then NULL (0) to terminate the parameter list.

Also - while `execve` normally does not return, robust code will take  into account the possibility that `execve` fails, and handle this properly.